# how could I go back to a specific revision in mecurial?

Tags: mercurial, revert, changeset

I have 4 changesets and I want to return to Revision 2 and cancel revisions 3 and 4. is this possible? and what is the command to type?

Comment: also, please remember to accept/upvote the answer if you found it helpful. As I can see in your profile you never do that, it's sort of bad manners.

Read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: yes it's true I never do that, thanks, i'll do it from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`hg update [-r REV]`** changes your working copy parent revision and also changes the file content to match this new parent revision. This means that new commits will carry on from the revision you update to.

and what exactly do you mean by 'cancel'? exclude them from existence? You can do that by using [strip](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/strip) command:

**`hg strip [-r REV]`**

which removes the changeset and all its descendants from the repository. It will be as if the changes never existed. this command is part of the [MqExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) which you need to [enable](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension#Configuration) first.